# Switch off phone through sms

Tags: html

i need coding to switch off the mobile(ex:-NOKIA) through sms from pc using any programming language

Comment: Are you programming a bomb ? ;)

Comment: how do you think about me? haa.....     i want develope some special type application so i need this.

Comment: do u know answer this question tell me and u dont know .......

Comment: What exact operaring systems are you working with here? those determine the language the client is written in. You can most likely write the desktop base in whatever you want.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that is necesarily legal to do that via sms. You could write a simple application for the phone that awaits a signal from the pc before running a sleep command. Never heard of a full remote shutdown via 3rd party developer tools before though.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible just on old Nokia Phones (with black & white screen) & with phone like Nokia 1600.

**Methode**
Write new text message that contain 51 inverted commas ["] in your message & send it to victim. For some mobile phone you need to write 79 inverted commas  instead of 51.

You can write comments in the start of message. For example "I am going to turn of your phone" & write commas after two lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you could do this over a SMS, and if there is a way do it (which I'm sure there is, nothing is impossible when it comes to technology), you would probably be breaking the law (even if you were only using it for something personal, since you would essentially be creating a virus that does something to the users phone without them approving it.